# selenium - java checkbox controlled

Tags: java

I wrote a test to see if 3 side-by-side check boxes can be clicked on in Selenium. When I wrote with isEnabled, it couldn't select the box, so I decided to use try-catch so that it could select the box.

```
try{
           sportCheckbox.click();
       }catch (ElementClickInterceptedException e){
           sportCheckboxlabel.click();
           System.out.println("Entered catch block!");
       }
```

I wrote it and then I got an error like this

java: unexpected type
required: class
found:    type parameter ElementClickInterceptedException

can you help me ? thanks

Comment: Do you have any type parameter which is named `ElementClickInterceptedException`. Like this; `class SomeClass<ElementClickInterceptedException> { ... }` ?
Or can you share much more code related with ElementClickInterceptedException?

Comment: I didn't create any parameters. After getting an isEnabled error, in the console
ElementClickInterceptedException
i got the error. and I tried to handle it by taking it directly from there.
How can I create the parameter? thank you so much

Comment: No, you don't have to create a parameter. The exception says "Java compiler wants a class but it gets a `Type Parameter`". This mean `ElementClickInterceptedException` is not a class reference, it's `Type Parameter`. Can your improve/edit your question by adding `ElementClickInterceptedException` related details?